# How to use NVM to switch Node versions for the Apache user ('www-data') - a user with severely limited functionality?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, node.js, www-data

I call a Node script from PHP on my Ubuntu web server, as in

```
// The following PHP executes in the context of the Apache user - 'www-data'
//
$execstring = "node " . $args;
exec($execstring, $output, $return_value);
```

As noted, the PHP code executes in the context of the Apache user, which is `www-data` by default on Ubuntu.

**I would like to be able to use `nvm` to switch Node versions for the `www-data`** user.

(Note: I might be able to switch Node versions *without* using `nvm` by specifying the full path to a different Node installation - I have not tried this yet, but it's not my question.)

Following instructions [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown#install-script), I install and use `nvm` quite easily for **other** users:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.0/install.sh | bash
```

and

```
nvm install 4.1.2
```

**I have found that I must install `nvm` separately for every user.**  This means that `nvm` does not install for the `www-data` user when I run the command above as the login user (`ubuntu`); and, conversely, switching my Node version for the login user (`ubuntu`) has no effect on the `www-data` user.

One more important detail: The `www-data` user is special.  This user has severely restricted functionality.  To switch to the `www-data` user in the shell, this special command is required:

```
sudo su www-data -s /bin/sh
```

(...And even the above command won't work without other, previous special steps, not noted here, to allow a shell prompt for the `www-data` user.)

**When logged in as the `www-data` user, however, although I seem to be able to *install* `nvm` using the command noted previously, I cannot *run* `nvm`.**  (The error is `nvm not found`.)

Attempting to overcome this, I made the brutal mistake of following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20674228/368896) to attempt to switch the Node version globally (i.e., for all users) while logged in as (I think, but forget now) the `root` user (oops!):

```
// Danger!  Do not do this!
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```

Unfortunately, running the above command caused my `sudo` access to break, and now I must apparently rebuild the server from scratch.

My question is: How can I install and use `nvm` as the Apache user (`www-data`) to allow a web server to run a Node process of a given version, and thereby control which version of Node the web server accesses - with the convenience of using `nvm`?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't.

NVM is a shell script that only just sets environment variables (mainly modifying your PATH) to change the active `node` version. As such, they are not persistent beyond the lifetime or process tree of the calling shell.

While you should be able to run your web server with particular environment variables, you can't use NVM to manage them since any call to `nvm` would be called in a subprocess of your web server and discarded as soon as the command terminates.